# Dynamic Lookup for multiple values in a cell (comma separated) and return the corresponding ID to a single cell (comma separated also)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

The thing is not always the amount of values (IDs) will be the same within each cell (at least 1, max=several) that's why the fixed version of using concatenated vlookup+left/mid/right will not work for me due to that will solution will only work up to 3 values. The only fixed size is the size of the values to lookup (IDs - in green), 8 characters (letters+numbers).

I'm not sure but, is it possible to setup a loop within excel formulas/functions ?
Below is a table containing an example of the issue I'm trying to resolve and the expected values (tables are in different tab). Hope you can help.
Thanks.

[example-tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teb6H.jpg)
[image]

Comment: It's probably possible to do it with a convoluted worksheet function but I would do it with a UDF, meaning VBA, meaning the workbook would have to become macro-enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have windows Excel O365 with the `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML` functions, you can use a formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(XLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(@[IDs],",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),Table2[IDs],Table2[IDv2]),"""--"""))
```

Note that, in your data, there are two ID's in `A4` that do not match any ID's in Table 2.  Although that may be a typo, I left them as is to demonstrate the error handling.

**Table1**
[image]

**Table2**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you nailed it. This is exactly what I was looking for. Using build-in excel functions if possible and you did it. Regarding the not matching ID, I forgot to mention that part but you also gave a solution to, as sometimes not all the "original" ID has a matching ID. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF that will do what you describe. Paste the code into a standard code module (not one already existing in the workbook but one that you create and that would have a name like `Module1` before you change it to what you like best. You can also rename the function to give it a more suitable name.

```
Function ID_v2(Cell As Range) As String
    ' 035

    Dim Fun         As String           ' function return value
    Dim Sp()        As String           ' array of CSVs of CellVal
    Dim VLRng       As Range            ' the lookup range
    Dim VL          As Variant          ' result of VLookup
    Dim i           As Integer          ' loop counter

    ' this is a range similar to your sample A10:D19
    Set VLRng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Table2").RefersToRange
    Sp = Split(Cell.Cells(1).Value, ",")
    If UBound(Sp) >= 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
            On Error Resume Next
            VL = Application.VLookup(Trim(Sp(i)), VLRng, 3, False)
            If Err Then VL = "[ERROR]"
            Fun = Fun & VL & ","
        Next i
        ID_v2 = Left(Fun, Len(Fun) - 1)      ' remove final comma
    End If
End Function
```

Call the function with syntax like built-in functions. For example,

```
= ID_v2(A3)
```

This can be copied down like any other function. But remember to save the workbook as macro-enabled.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Although using VBA will significantly increase the file size (currently 140MB) I could divide it and using as secondary solution.
I haven't tested yet but I will and provide feedback. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Cell2List()
        Dim wF As WorksheetFunction: Set wF = Application.WorksheetFunction 'To user Transpose
        Dim i As Range
        Dim j As Range
        Dim s As String: s = "," 'The separator of the list

        'Ask the user for the cell where are the list with the commas
        'Just need to select the cell
        Set i = Application.InputBox("Select just one cell where the values are", "01. Selecte the values", , , , , , 8)

        'Ask the for the separator. If you are completely sure the comma will never change just delete this line
        s = Application.InputBox("Tell me, what is the character separator, just one character! (optional)", "02. Separator (comma semicolon colon or any other char)", , , , , , 2)
        If s = "" Then s = "," 'Verifying...........

        'Ask the user where want to put the list
        'You need to get ready the cells to receive the list.
        'If there any data will be lost, the macro will overwrite anything in the cells
        Set j = Application.InputBox("Select just one cell where the values will go as a list, just one cell!", "03. Selecte the cell", , , , , , 8)

        Dim myArr: myArr = (Split(i.Value, s)) 'Split the list into a Array


        Range(Cells(j.Row, j.Column), Cells(j.Row + UBound(myArr), j.Column)).Value = wF.Transpose(myArr)
        'j.Row is the row of the cell the user selected to put the cell
        'j.Column the same, but the column
        'j.Row + UBound(myArr) =      UBound(myArr) is the total count of elements in the list
        '                            +j.Row
        '                            _______________
        '                            the last cell of the new list!
        'wF.Transpose(myArr) = we need to "flip" the array... Don't worry, but Don't change it!
    End Sub
```

You can put this macro with a button tin the ribbons, or use it as you can see in the gif

[image]

And this will be the result: (with a bigger list)

[image]

**EDIT**

You can use this UDF:

```
Function Cells2List(List As Range, Pos As Integer) As String
    Cells2List = Split(List, ",")(Pos - 1)
End Function
```

Just need to define and index this way:

[image]

To tell the function, what index you want to see. You can use the function using `ROW()-#` to define an 1 at the beginning and when the formula send a `#VALUE!` delete the formulas. Where `$A$1` is where the list are, and `D7` is where the index are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check and let you know.